# Multiple labels on a single bounding box for tensorflow SSD mobilenet

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, object-detection-api

I have configured SSD mobilenet v1 and have trained the model previously as well. However in my dataset for each of the bounding box there are multiple class labels. My dataset is of faces each face have 2 labels: age and gender. Both these labels have the same bounding box coordinates.

After training on this dataset the problem that I encounter is that the model only labels the gender of the face and not the age. In yolo however both gender and age can be shown.

Is it possible to achieve multiple labels on a single bounding box using SSD mobile net ?

Comment: there was a discussion about it but I doubt the official api supports it at the moment. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the implementation but SSD uses a softmax layer to predict a single class per bounding box, whereas YOLO predicts individual sigmoid confidence scores for each class. So in SSD a single class with argmax gets picked but in YOLO you can accept multiple classes above a threshold.

However you are really doing a multi-task learning problem with two types of outputs, so you should extend these models to predict both types of classes jointly.